# Phileo Django Liking App

Tags: django, pinax

I have followed the instructions here [Phileo Docs](http://phileo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#id1) and I added my model to the LIKABLE_MODELS, I added a widget in my template but it is not working. In the admin the Phileo table Like is also emplty. When I press the like button i am redirected to this page `http://localhost:8000/likes/like/19:1/` but nothing happens and the count ofcourse stays the same. When I add a like from the admin it does appear on the template but it doesn't work vice verse.

Has anyone faced a similar problem or anyn idea how to fix this?

Comment: try manually download && install it from here https://github.com/pinax/phileo there is 1.3.1 but via `pip install` 1.3

Comment: Thanks but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what was missing.

From the [docs](http://phileo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

> ```
> {% load staticfiles %}
> <script src="{% static "js/eldarion-ajax.min.js" %}"></script>
> ```
>
> This of course is optional. You can roll your own javascript handling
>   as the view also returns data in addition to rendered HTML.
>   Furthermore, if you don’t want ajax at all the view will handle a
>   regular POST and perform a redirect.

Comment: so accept your answer :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow